# How many controllers can connect to a PS2?

Tags: controllers, ps2

Some people say two, some say eight (by using Multitaps). What is the maximum number of controllers that can be connected to a PS2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be 8 if you were using Multitaps because each Multitap can use 4 controllers. If you weren't using Multitaps it would only be 2.

Comment: Can we add 2 multitaps in a PS2?

Comment: Yes you can, some games do support 8 players but as far as i know it only supports 4 games.

Micro Machines V3,
Micro Maniacs,
Madden NFL 99 and
Monopoly